# How to print file comparison

Tags: phpstorm

I know how to compare two files in PhpStorm...it displays a very nice analysis of the differences.  But I can't figure out how to save the analysis to a file or to print out the comparison.  I've searched the PhpStorm documentation and I've clicked all over the place in the differences viewer, but can't see how to save the output so that I can send it to my team.

Maybe this functionality has not been added yet?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: There are little arrows in the middle, you can check which one is which and then simply send a modification to another one, It is also possible to compare with clipboard

Comment: I know how to read the differences report and how to merge the code...what I don't know how to do is to save the differences report to a file to send out for review.

Comment: i think it save them automaticly. whenever you change something it changes it in your code.